# ExternalInterface.call where to find?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

I have a flash file that I am trying to work with. I am below than a basic user of ActionScript. There is not much documentation for the project and old developer is not here.

I am trying to change some JavaScript function. Below function calls a JavaScript function

```
ExternalInterface.call
```

In the object tag of HTML the JavaScript is on

```
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"/>
```

I am confused because there is no JS file in the flash project or on the page that embed swf file. I didn't even find that function in any .AS file. There is no JS inclusion in the flash file either.

Am I missing something?

### Edit

It connects to  RTMP server on 80 and 1935 ports. Is it possible that JS is located on RTMP server?

Comment: this js code could be added early in the as3 by the same _ExternalInterface.call_ method. Many developers use this approach - add some js on initialization and call it later whenever it is needed

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I tried to search javascript function in .as file without any luck. The method name is "refresh_cont". There is no method with this name in any of the .as file.

Comment: What does removing the call do?

Comment: It does not refresh the contents.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function callJS():* {

  if (ExternalInterfaceUtil.available) {
     try {
        var param: Object = {/*your params*/};
        var functionName: String = "function (arg) { try {  /* - some code here - */ } catch (err) {} }";
        ExternalInterface.call(functionName, param);
     } catch (e:Error) {
        debug(e.toString());
     }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Please note that you can write any js code in functionName variable. It's like block of javascript code inside AS3.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example. I am aware of such cases. However, in my .AS files there is no such case. Is there a way that a person can upload JS on RTMP server and remotely call the function? Even, in this method a .AS file should have inclusion of .JS file, no?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not familiar with RTMP server.

In my sample you don't need to include .js files. But you have to run your swf in browser.

Comment: Your example is working fine. However, I am still unable to find any JS code inside actionscript files. Is there any other way to remotely include JS in the flash files?

Comment: Try to debug this function with DevTools. You will see the stack of calls and probably find it in some html or js resources.

Comment: Which devtool? I tried Chrome devTools but it does not debug .swf file.